# Laço de repetição não está executando

Tags: c, c++, loop

Estou fazendo um código em que tem um vetor (com 15 posições) com valores pré-determinados (10 valores quaisquer e 5 vezes o valor 0), e onde o usuário irá informar um novo valor para ir ao final da lista (substituindo o 0).

Parece-me que está tudo certo aqui, mas o vetor não "pega" o valor digitado. Ele executa tudo certinho, sem erro algum, apenas não faz a substituição do 0 pelo novo valor.

Segue o código (como faz parte de um código maior, um `switch` com 7 opções, vou colocar só essa parte com erro pra não ficar muito grande e com partes desnecessárias):

```
    case 1 : printf("Qual valor voce quer inserir no final? ");
               scanf ("%d",&x1);
  n1 = 15;//posições do vetor
  num = 1;
  x2 = 1;
            printf("lista atual:\n"); //Exibe como está a lista
            while (num <= n1)
            {
                printf ("%d ", vet[num]);
                num++;
            }
            while (num <= n1) //roda o laço e caso encontre uma posição do vetor igual a zero, subtitui
            {
                if (vet[num] == 0)
                {
                    vet[num] = x1;
                }
               num++;
            }
            printf ("\n\nNova lista:\n");
            while (num <= n1)
            {
                printf ("%d", vet[num]);
                num++;
            }
```

Comment: Lembra-te que os arrays em C começam no indice `0`, e vao até ao indice `N - 1`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você não está reiniciando a variável `num` que é usada como contadora. Tem duas soluções:

```
while (num < n1) {
    printf ("%d ", vet[num]);
    num++;
}
num = 0;
while (num < n1) {
    if (vet[num] == 0) {
        vet[num] = x1;
    }
   num++;
}
```

Também poderia fazer o mesmo com `for`, aí evita essa confusão:

```
for (int num = 0; num < n1; num++) {
    printf ("%d ", vet[num]);
}
for (int num = 0; num < n1; num++) {
    if (vet[num] == 0) {
        vet[num] = x1;
    }
}
```

Note que estou começando o `num` com 0, me parece ser o mais correto mas não posso garantir sem ver o resto. Se o certo for 1 mesmo, é só mudar.

Mas para evitar este problema também pode aproveitar e fazer tudo em um laço só:

```
for (int num = 0; num < n1; num++) {
    printf ("%d ", vet[num]);
    if (vet[num] == 0) {
        vet[num] = x1;
    }
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Loop/Variations.c).

Comment: Valeu, Bigown, funcionou e ficou mais enxuto o código. Por´me, vou ter que trocar minha lógica e reorganizar o código, pois, assim como eu fiz (comparando e substituindo o que for 0) ele tá colocando o valor digitado em todos os 0's e não só no primeiro deles. Mais uma coisa, este for com todos os elementos em uma só linha é C ou C++? Pois tenho que implentar em C.

Comment: Ambos. É C, portanto é C++ também. Ele é sempre preferível quando pode. Na verdade conheço programador que só usa o `for` e nunca usa `while`. Acho um exagero mas é possível. No seu caso o `for` é bem intuitivo porque você tem claramente uma inicialização de variável, uma condição para indicar o fim e um processamento que deve ser executado em cada passo. Ele lida melhor com escopo. http://www.ime.usp.br/~elo/IntroducaoComputacao/Comando%20de%20repeticao%20for.htm Sabe inglês? http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_for_loop.htm http://www.learn-c.org/en/For_loops Lembre-se o [tour].

Answer (score 0):

```
        while (num <= n1)
        {
            printf ("%d ", vet[num]);
            num++;
        }
```

No fim deste primeiro ciclo, o valor de `num` vai ser `n1 + 1`

```
        while (num <= n1) //roda o laço e caso encontre uma posição do vetor igual a zero, subtitui
```

este ciclo nunca vai executar, pois logo na primeira vez a condição é falsa (`num == n1 + 1`).

Comment: Pmg, mas aquele primeiro laço ao qual você se referiu é apenas o laço pra printar a lista atual na tela. Ele tá rodando certinho. O problema é no laço seguinte, aquele que você colocou a primeira linha. Obrigado

Comment: No fim do primeiro ciclo, o valor da variável `num` é `n1 + 1`. A condição do segundo ciclo é falsa, por isso o segundo ciclo não executa uma única vez.